# Inserting Numbered TOC in Specific RMarkdown Page with Docx

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working with Rmarkdown and trying to generate a Table of Contents (TOC) that appears on a specific page of my document. I'm using a reference .docx file to style the headings and subheadings, and I would like to insert the TOC on the third page of my .docx file.

Here is my **word_generator.Rmd file:**

```
---
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template1.docx
---

::: {custom-style="heading_2"}
Lorem Ipsum Title
:::


::: {custom-style="heading_2"}
Trademarks
:::


::: {custom-style="link_type1"}
[www.loremipsum.com](www.loremipsum.com)
:::

\newpage

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(flextable)
library(officeR)


report_values <- data.frame(
  Fiction = "1200",
  NonFiction = "800"
)

# Create a summary data frame with formatted strings
book_summary <- data.frame(
  "Fiction books in the library:" = paste(report_values$Fiction, "books"),
  "Non-Fiction books in the library:" = paste(report_values$NonFiction, "books")
)

book_summary_tbl <- book_summary %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  flextable()
```

I am aiming to add the TOC contents right after the content mentioned above in the .Rmd file. I've looked into adding a generated Table of Contents anywhere in RMarkdown by referring to this [guide](https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/add-a-generated-table-of-contents-anywhere-in-rmarkdown/), but I couldn’t get the TOC as needed. The issues were that it appeared without the numberings, and clicking on the contents did not navigate to the necessary headings.

You can download the [reference docx file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9lezxoxrauz4ls9wsia8h/template1.docx?rlkey=ddf6gbmh7qgsa4o57lzjiu7bn&dl=0)

Thank you for the help.